# How to force merge a git tag?

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to do `git merge` a tag but running into below error, earlier I had a folder with the similar name where I merged this tag ,later I had to delete and recreate and remerge but somehow git remembers I merged it earlier, how do I force merge it?

```
username-MacBook-Pro-2:HW_4355 username$ git merge -X theirs TAGNAME_REL_9_130_16_2
merge: TAGNAME_REL_9_130_16_2- not something we can merge
```

Comment: do `git cat-file -t TAGNAME_REL_9_130_16_2` to see what kind of thing that is.